# A Lipschitzian's condition for the measure of nonconvexity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, convexity, convex-analysis, compactness

I'm actually working on the measure of nonconvexity and its application. Especially, the  [Eisenfeld–Lakshmikantham MNC](https://rc.library.uta.edu/uta-ir/bitstream/handle/10106/2198/MathTechReport026.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) defined - in a Banach space - by:

$$\alpha(A)=\sup_{b\in\overline{\operatorname{conv}}(A)} \inf_{a\in A}|| b-a \|<\infty $$
Alternatively, if $H(X, Y)$ denotes the Hausdorff distance between two subsets $X$ and $Y$,
$$\alpha(A)=H(A, \overline{\operatorname{conv}}(A))$$

where $\operatorname{conv}(A)$ is the convex hull of $A$.

The interesting thing about the E-L MNC is that $\alpha(A)=0 \Longrightarrow \overline{A} \text{ is convex}.$

---

Note that **if** a function $f$ is $\lambda$-norm-Lipschitzian, **then** the measure of (weak) noncompactness of De Blasi ($\beta$) is $\lambda$-Lipschitzian, that is $$\beta(f(X))\leq \lambda \beta(X)$$

Note that

$$
\beta(X)=\inf \left\{\varepsilon>0: \exists \text { weakly compact } Y \text { with } X \subset Y+\varepsilon B_E\right\} \text {, }
$$

**Is there a similar sufficient condition to have the $\lambda$-Lipschitzian property for the measure of nonconvexity.**

**$$\alpha(f(X))\leq \lambda \alpha(X)$$**

**Unfortunately, the $\lambda$-norm-Lipschitzianity of $f$ is not enough.**

*I think, at some stage, we need that $\overline{\operatorname{Conv}}(f(X))\subseteq f(\overline{\operatorname{Conv}}(X))$*

---

**Edit**: After many discussions with colleagues, it's hard to impose a contraction condition with respect to $\alpha$. It's a very restrictive condition.

Now I'm looking for an example of an operator $T:C\subset E\to C$ and a decreasing sequence $\left\{X_{n}\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $T$-invariant subsets of $C$,  such that

$$\alpha(\left\{X_{n}\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}})\underset{n\to \infty}{\rightarrow}0.$$

Comment: If $X$ is convex then $\alpha(X) = 0$, right? So the inequality $\alpha(f(X)) \leq \lambda\alpha(X)$ implies $\alpha(f(X)) = 0$, hence $\overline{f(X)}$ is convex. So $f$ basically has to take convex sets to convex sets, which is pretty close to saying $f$ is linear ...

Comment: Yes, that's a great analysis, I expected this condition of linearity, but I wish I have something for nonlinear operators..

Comment: What is $\beta$?

Comment: @MattF. I added a line about it!